# How to use only Light Theme on xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

On the phone, I have a dark theme. How on Android I can you only Light theme?

I updated the visual studio, and now I have the same theme of the program as on the phone, it is dark on the phone, and I want the program to be light, please help.

I tried

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme.Light
```

but it does not work

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/app-themes-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `AppThemeBinding` to set the light theme when the phone is dark or not.

Download the source file from the link below and make some changes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-systemthemesdemo/

When you set dark mode on the phone and want the program to be light, you could change the xaml to set the light theme like below:

**Change:** ContentPage BackgroundColor

```
 BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPageBackgroundColor}}">
```

**To:**

```
 BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}, Dark={StaticResource LightPageBackgroundColor}}">
```

**Change:** Grid BackgroundColor

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}">
```

**To:**

```
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The following requirements must be met for a system design change to respond to Xamarin.Forms:

- Xamarin.Forms4.6.0.967 or higher
- Android 10 (API 29) or higher

Then you can run this code;

```
Application.Current.UserAppTheme = OSAppTheme./*Light, Dark or Unspecified*/;
```

When your devive run on android 9 you have to set this in your application theme;

```
<application android:label="MyApp" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
</application>
```

Have a look on [this repository](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/ThemeSwitcher) for more details.

[image]